# Power Automate flow to trigger PowerApps

Tags: automation, power-automate, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I have a canvas app that has a send email button. This button has the following OnSelect property:

`Office365Outlook.SendEmailV2(Emails_uitn.Text,Emailsubject_uitn.Text,Emailbody_uitn.Text)`

This button works exactly how I want it to work.
I want to create a scheduled flow in PowerAutomate that will trigger this button. I have an excel list with a date column. I want the flow to check if today is equal to any of the dates in the column. If yes, the SendEmail action should be triggered. Alternatively, I could build the SendEmail action directly in the flow and retrieve the subject, body, and recipients from PowerApps.

I have tried a few different methods to do this and I am stumped. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps:

1. Create a new Power Automate flow and set the trigger as Schedule flow
2. Set the trigger to run daily
3. Read your Excel file using the Excel reader step
4. Do `Apply to each` on the previous step, and use `Condition` to check if today's date (`utcNow()`) is equal to any of your date values in the file
5. If the condition is met, put your follow-up desired step in the `YES` section

Comment: Yes but I'm stuck on what to put in the yes section. How do I make it get the data from powerapps if yes?

Comment: If you want to pull data from PowerApps you can only do that with `PowerApps V2` or `PowerApps` trigger. But in that you can only trigger the flow from PowerApps only on any Action, like on a click of a button